# install R 2.11.x on El Capitan

Tags: r, osx-elcapitan

Hi I am using program the needs to have R 2.11.x installed on my Mac with El Capitan. However, when I try to install this I get an error message saying that R.2.11 version is not supported in Leopard or previous versions of OS. Please let me know if there is a get around to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: This might be better on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/), or even SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

R 2.11 is **ancient**. No wonder you can’t install it.

If you really need this old version, the only recourse is to use a different PC or a virtual machine with another operating system installed on it.

But chances are you should use a much newer version of R.